# Adding user access level into process login?

Tags: php

Is there anyway that I'll be able to add user access level through this process code?  I have my register code, which will allow normal user to register.  I will set the admin only through PHPMyAdmin.  How can I define admin user access level with this process page?

**CODE: login_process.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ./protected_page.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ./index.php?error=1');
    }
} 

else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
?>
```

**Code: Login function**

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
        FROM members
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Code:**

```
    if (login($username="admin_username") {
            // Login admin success 
            header('Location: ./protected_page.php');
} else （login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true）{
            // Login success
            header('Location: ./user.php');
        }
} else {
            // Login failed 
            header('Location: ./index.php?error=1');
        }
```

Comment: When you've validated the login, set a session with the user level in it before you redirect to protected_page.php

Comment: i've added example code, will that work?

Comment: You can redirect to the same place if you want to, the important thing is to store the user_level value in the session on successful login. Then, you can do whatever you want in your application because you can easily tell what level the user is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how you are storing the data in your database but if your user table has columns : user_name, password, user_type.

when you check if user_name and the password match on your login function you could do :

```
SELECT user_name, password, user_type FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password"'";
```

Then you check the number of returned rows, if 0 is returned then the credentials don't match, you don't log the user in. If they match, then you can use the `user_level` to redirect where you want.

If you can post your login function I could explain you showing the changes to do into the code.

edit : adding fixed functions after he posted he login function.

Login validation :

```
    include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
    include_once 'includes/functions.php';

    sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

    if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

        if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Login success
            //Redirecting to admin protected page for instance
            if( isset($_session['user_type']) and $_session['user_type'] == 'admin' )
                header('Location: ./protected_page.php');
            else {
                //redirect to normal logged user
                header('Location: ./normal_user_logged.php');

            }


        } else {
            // Login failed 
            header('Location: ./index.php?error=1');
        }
    } 

    else {
        // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
        echo 'Invalid Request';
    }
?>
```

Login function :

```
    function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, user_type 
        FROM members
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $user_type);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```